# Object with eventhandler overloading

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Currently I'm trying to write a resourcemanager in JavaScript. It has two methods, one to add a image resource to the manager, and one that preloads all the images after they are added:

```
ResourceManager = function(){};
ResourceManager.prototype = function(){

 var imageList = new Array(),
     
     addImage = function(imageUrl){
      imageList.push(imageUrl);
     },
     loadImages = function(){
      //Do stuff for loading here
      onComplete();
     },
     onComplete = function(){
      alert('finished');
     };

     return {
      addImage: addImage,
      loadImages: loadImages,
      onComplete: onComplete
     }
}();
```

Then I want to use it as following:

```
var rsmgr = new ResourceManager();
rsmgr.onComplete = function(){
 alert('completed');
};
rsmgr.addImage('image.png');
rsmgr.loadImages();
```

You can see a working example [on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RPgTu/)

Now this overload is not working, so why does this happen? I'm guessing it has to do with the prototyping but I can't seem to grasp on how to fix this.

Comment: You linked to jsFiddle main site, no working code there.

Comment: Thanks for the notice, I've now linked to the proper page.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert in prototyping, so can't give valid response why it's not working however I can suggest alternative way using "pure function" approach that works just fine:

```
function ResourceManager() {
    this.imageList = new Array();

    this.addImage = function(imageUrl) {
        this.imageList.push(imageUrl);
    };

    this.loadImages = function() {
        //Do stuff for loading here
        this.onComplete();
    };

    this.onComplete = function() {
        alert('finished');
    };
};
```

Having it written like the above cause your original override code to work - [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RPgTu/1/).
(If you remove the `rsmgr.onComplete` override you'll get "finished" as expected)